# Initiate EC2 instance with pack of comands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to start AWS EC2 instance with pack of commands?
So im creating a new instance and thing i wan't to achieve is run some linux commands automatically after starting it without connecting with machine and typing those commands manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

You would list your script (bash for Linux, or Powershell for Windows), this will then run on the first time the instance runs.

An example user data taken from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-console) to perform the setup of a web server is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
yum install -y httpd mariadb-server
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

In the event you need to debug take a look at the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` log once the instance has launched.

However, if there are a larger number of steps it might be preferable to create a [pre-baked AMI](https://medium.com/@sebolabs/bake-or-not-to-bake-10af1f6ccb96) which involves setting up a blank server with all the necessary services and configuration using a tool such as [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/) or [Puppet](https://puppet.com/).

Comment: Can I invoke those bash commands from lambda function, when starting instance from lambda?

Comment: Are you creating the instance via the Lambda function? If you're using the SDK in the Lambda then yes you can, for example: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances there is a parameter named `UserData`.